# python define values for each data-frame if they meet a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, conditional-statements

i have 5 different data frames that are output of different conditions or tables.

i want to have an output if these data-frames are empty or not. basically i will define with len(df) each data frame and will pass a string if they have anything in them.

```
def(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5)

if len(df1) > 0:
"df1 not empty"
else: ""

if len(df2) > 0:
"df2 not empty"
else: ""
```

then i want to append these string to each other and will have a string like

```
**df1 not empty, df3 not empty**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = {'milk': pd.DataFrame(['a']), 'bread': pd.DataFrame(['b']), 'potato': pd.DataFrame()}

print(''.join(
    [f'{name} not empty. ' for name, df in dfs.items() if (not df.empty)])
      )
```

output:

```
milk not empty. bread not empty.
```

Comment: can i call the df names accordingly maybe? instead of numerating them lets say. df1 = bread df2 = milk etc. says bread df not empty, milk df not empty

Comment: you mean instead of printing df1, df2 ... you want their names ?

Comment: yes you can , but in that case (in the code I gave you) you should use a dictionnary (there is an alternative way to get the variable name that hosts the df but its not recommended. I edited the code so it does what you want.

Comment: this works, if i could up 1000 times your solution i would :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1']) #create not empty df

data1 = []
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data) #create empty df

dfs = [df, df1] #list them

#the "for loop" is replaced here by a list comprehension
#I used enumerate() to attribute an index to each df in the list of dfs, because otherwise in the print output if you call directly df0 or df1 it will print th entire dataframe, not only his name
print(' '.join([f'df{i} is not empty.' for i,df in enumerate(dfs) if not df.empty]))
```

Result:

```
df0 is not empty. df1 is not empty.
```

Comment: but then i would have only 1 output multiplied by how many dfs meets the condition.

instead i want the explanation of what dfs are meeting this and print 1 output by this. 

len(df1) = 1, len(df2) = 0 , len(df3) =3

when i apply this as,
`for df in dfs:
  if len(df)>0:
    print('string)`

result would be
2 times `string`

Comment: My bad, Updated :)

Answer (score 0):

With a one-liner:

```
dfs = [df1,df2,df3,df4,df5]
output = ["your string here" for df in dfs if not df.empty]
```

You can then concatenate strings together, if you want:

```
final_string = "; ".join(output)
```